# Как можно переопределить систему координат?

Tags: java, swing, графика

Допустим, я рисую какую-то прямоугольную область, а затем хочу внутри нее нарисовать еще, что-нибудь, но в координатах, относительно этого прямоугольника. То есть, что бы началом координат был не верхний левый угол окна, а верхний левый угол прямоугольной области, а 1 шаг по осям `X` и `Y` был не 1 пиксель, а какая-то своя единица измерения, например, одна клетка сетки.

Я знаю, что можно получить эти координаты с помощью `rectArea.getX()`, `rectArea.getY()`, а линии сетки рисовать, к примеру, через каждые 50 пикселей и тогда рисовать точки на графике учитывая это, но хотелось бы именно переопределить систему координат. Есть ли какие-то методы для этого?

Comment: что по Вашему значит переопределить? сдвинуть относительно нуля? отмасштабировать? повернуть? все вместе?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Сдвинуть относительно нуля и изменить шаг на свой

Comment: ctx.translate(), ctx.scale()

Comment: @StrangerintheQ это из canvas? JS? А на java можно?))

Comment: это java, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#scale(double,%20double) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#translate(double,%20double)